# Call the javascript function from the layout with the javascript code from the partial view asp.net core

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have partial view that loading data from database table. I need from a partial view to transfer data to a function that is located on the layout and calling it. However, I heard that render sections do not work in asp.net core in the partial representations. But I really need to call function from layout.

The general logic is this. The partial view is loaded, the field of which the user selects the line, presses the delete button. The delete button sends data to the controller, the controller deletes the entry and returns the json object. Then the code is called from the layout.

My code, layout footer:

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
function AjaxLoad(data) {

                console.log(data);
                console.log('*********');

                if (data.action == "error") {
                    alert(data.message);
                    return;
                }
                else if (data.action == "load") {
                    CurrentTable = data.table
                }

                if (data.page != null || data.page != undefined) {
                    PageIndex = data.page;
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/ListView",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        Table: CurrentTable,
                        Page: PageIndex
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('#PartialViewId').html("<p>" +  "@NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Loading" + " \"" + LangCurrentTable + "\"...</p>");
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#TableId").html("<p>" + LangCurrentTable + "</p>");
                        $("#PartialViewId").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#PartialViewId").html("@NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Error" + ":" + LangCurrentTable);
                    }
                });

                $("#AddId").css("visibility","visible");
            };

  });
    </script>

@if (IsSectionDefined("EtcScripts"))
    {
        @RenderSection("EtcScripts")
    }
```

Delete button (link):

```
<a asp-action="Delete" asp-controller="Admin" asp-route-Id="@record.Id" asp-route-Table="@ViewBag.Table"
                   asp-route-Page="@ViewBag.Page" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-failure="onFailed" data-ajax-success="AjaxLoad" data-ajax-update="#PartialViewId">
                    @NanoWiki.Resources.Translations.Delete
                </a>
```

Contoller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string Table, int? Id, int? Page)
        {
            pageIndex = Page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(Page) : 1;

            if (!Id.HasValue)
            {
                obj = new { message = Resources.Translations.UpsErrorMessage, action = "error" };
                return Json(obj);
            }

            var result = Connector.SQLQuery("DELETE FROM " + Table + " WHERE Id = " + Id);

            if (result == false)
            {
                obj = new { message = Resources.Translations.UpsErrorMessage, action = "error" };
                return Json(obj);
            }

            obj = new { table = Table, page = pageIndex, action = "load" };
            return Json(obj);
        }
```

How can I send data from `AjaxLoad` to the layout?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to do this ?

Comment: Because it is necessary. We delete the record and immediately download the entire list of records. This is convenient for the user